# Define my own short-verb like macro?

Tags: macros, verbatim, typewriter

I'm trying to define shorthand macros for `\texttt` that are a bit like the `\verb` ones. The end result is to do `+asdf+` and this have the same effect as `\texttt{asdf}`. This is like the `DefineShortVerb` command in the `fancyvrb` package, but instead of verbatim I want `texttt` as the underlying command.

First, I can obtain a macro like `\ttt+asdf+` via the `xparse` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
% want \ttt[delimiter]#1[delimiter] for \texttt{#1}:
\NewDocumentCommand\ttt{v}{%
    \texttt{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\ttt+asdf+
\end{document}
```

This works.

Is there some way to take the next step and use `[delimiter]asdf[delimiter]` to mean `\texttt{asdf}`?

For example, if I were using `fancyvrb` I'd use `DefineShortVerb`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\+}
\begin{document}
+asdf+ % typesets a verbatim 'asdf'
\end{document}
```

My question is: **Is there any way I can emulate this behaviour but using `\texttt` as the base command as opposed to `\verb`?**.

It doesn't have to be as sophisticated as providing a `DefineShortVerb` macro; I'd just like the `[delmiter]text[delimiter]` functionality.

(Another way to go about it - is there some way I can override a `fancyvrb` command to use `\texttt` instead of `\verb` as the base command?)

cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `+` (or whatever symbol you choose) into a command character and then use `\def` to have it do whatever you want:

```
documentclass{article}

\catcode`+=\active
\def+#1+{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
+abc def+
\end{document}
```

Here `` \catcode`+=\active `` makes `+` an “active” character and then `\def+#1+{\texttt{#1}}` defines `+` as a macro that takes one parameter that is delineated by another `+` and passed to `\texttt`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after - thanks a lot! I had a look at the source for the `shortvrb` package but it's a bit too complicated for me at my current level of TeX mastery. Thanks for the explanation too.

Comment: you defined in '+'. When we use + sign in math mode "+" sign clashing. Check it.

Comment: I know. I just chose '+' as an example for the delimiter - I can make it anything I like.

Comment: @S.Murugan: That happens with any symbol you use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check this will work fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\verb+asdf+  typesets a verbatim 'asdf' $a+b+c$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not what I was after. I know about fancyvrb and `\verb+asdf+`, but what I want is to achieve the affects of `\DefineShortVerb{\+}` with `+asdf+` (or any delimiter of my choosing really), but instead using `\texttt` intead of verbatim.